# Ввод данных в С. Не определяется GetString() из cs50

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, cs50

Почему у меня не определяется `string s = GetString();`?

**hell.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("State our name: ");
    string s = GetString();
    printf("hello, %s\n", s);
}
```

> cc hell.c -o hell
>
> ```
> /tmp/ccHZXs2m.o: In function `main'
> hell.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `GetString'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make: *** [hell] Error 1
> ```

Comment: Скорее всего, проблема с установкой библиотеки cs50.

Comment: Как яхту назовешь так она и поплывет :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему бы тебе не воспользоваться методом `scanf()` для чтения с консоли?

```
int main(void) {
    string name;
    printf("Введите ваше имя");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Привет, %s\n!", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: на что указывает `name` и куда будет записана введённая строка?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, `string` в CS50 - это просто typedef-name для `char *`. В такой ситуации вышеприведенное "решение" - полнейшая белиберда.

Comment: @AnT [верно](http://mirror.cs50.net/library50/c/cs50-library-c-3.0/cs50.h)

Answer (score 4):

Нужно скомпилировать и слинковать с файлом cs50.c

```
cc -c help.c -o help.o
cc -c cs50.c -o cs50.c
cc -o help help.o cs50.o
```

Comment: Опечатка в cs50 команде. Плюс, можно как библиотеку использовать `-lcs50`, а не компилировать каждый раз.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что у тебя нету такой функции GetString().
Добавь например выше..

```
string GetString(void)
{
 return "test";
}
```

Comment: Эта функция определена в cs50.h

Comment: Прикрепи тогда хидер тоже) А то приходится гадать)

Comment: Во-первых, я не автор вопроса, а во-вторых из кода видно, что в инклудах используется некая сторонняя либа и прежде чем отвечать на вопрос, не плохо бы ознакомится с оной. Нагуглить же хидер не составляет проблем: http://mirror.cs50.net/library50/c/cs50-library-c-3.0/cs50.h Но можно было уточнить и у топикстартера.

Comment: А ну понятно, что делается. Значит, этот файлик надо с проектом слинковать. Видишь ошибка, что не видит функцию.

Answer (score 1):

Могу предположить, что у вас слетели или не были настроены переменные среды **CFLAGS** и **LDLIBS**. Попробуйте создать в этой же папке файл с названием **makefile** и поместить в него данные строки:

```
CC=clang
CFLAGS=-ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror
LDLIBS=-lcs50 -lm
```

После чего просто вызовите make:

```
make hell
```

for ABC ;)

Answer (score 1):

**На 22.08.2020 работает так:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    string name = get_string("State our name: ");
    if (name == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Hello, %s\n", name);
}
```

https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/c/

Answer (score 0):

Потому что cs50  это библиотека курса гарварда cs50.  А у Вас она не установлена. Запустите в их удаленной линуксовой среде и там подцепится.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте консоль в редакторе (отдельная иконка рядом с gedit). Тогда независимо от того, подключите ли вы библиотеку `string.h` или нет, функция `GetString` сработает.

Answer (score 0):

`.h` файл только **декларирует** список функций,

для их использования в программу должен быть вкомпилирован их код находящийся скорее всего в `.c`шных файлах (но может оказаться в .asm .haskell ... .lib .dll .so .a)

в самом простейшем случае у вас где-то должен лежать файл cs50.c, который тоже нужно скомпилировать:

```
gcc -o ./hello[.exe] hello.c cs50/lib/src/cs50.c
```

PS: описание принципа использования модулей, раздельной компиляции и использования ключевого слова `static` неплохо объяснено в [курсе Евгения Линского](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0d9LscUhb8)

Answer (score 0):

В окружении CS50 на [c9.io](http://c9.io/) начиная с **2016** эту функцию переименовали в:

```
get_string()
```

Используйте её или найдите более свежие видео-лекции.

Answer (score -3):

Потому, что ты не читал нормально начало к заданиям - ТАМ ТАК ЖИРНО написано ЦТ

Дополнительные материалы
reference.cs50.net/ — разъяснение функций библиотек, используемых во время обучения. На английском. 
http://computer.howstuffworks.com/c.htm стр. 11 – 14 и 39

И вот если пройти в разъяснение функций библиотек - и поискать поиском string - то будет чудо, выяснится что надо подключать библиотеку string.h - а она не прописана в cs50 - ребята не на все делали костыль! Зачем костыль на библиотеку готовую?